# Unknown crashes happening for Invalid Cast Exception "TappedRoutedEventArgs" -> "FrameworkElement"

Tags: windows, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

```
Specified cast is not valid.","stack_trace":"System InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows UI Xaml Input TappedRoutedEventArgs' to type 'Windows UI Xaml FrameworkElement'     at GalaSoft MvvmLight Command RelayCommand`1 Execute(Object parameter)    at Microsoft Xaml Interactions Core InvokeCommandAction Execute(Object sender  Object parameter)    at Microsoft Xaml Interactivity Interaction ExecuteActions(Object sender  ActionCollection actions  Object parameter)    at Microsoft Xaml Interactions Core EventTriggerBehavior OnEvent(Object sender  Object eventArgs
```

I have been getting a lot of this exception for my Windows Phone Store App from the store crash report.But not able to figure out the issue.Please help.

Comment: What code is executing? Without source, I can't say more than look for an invalid cast.

Comment: The problem is I am not able to figure out the code where the fault is.My entire source code is huge

Comment: Have you looked at the code where the crash is happening?

Comment: Had I known the code where the crash is happening I would have solved the issue.Saw at-least 10 crashes daily for this exceptions.Simply unable to recognize the cause or the place.Helpless

Comment: Put some instrumentation/debugging around those calls. The error is very specific.

Comment: Check converters if you're using some.